# Send email attachment created in HttpContext.Current.Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am creating a pdf using itextsharp. The pdf created normally and post it to the browser so the user can easily save the file to his computer . Now i want this generated pdf automatically send it also with email . I have try to convert the doc before post it to context and attach it to an email but with no any success. My code is:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=mypdf.pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

string imagepath = Server.MapPath(".") + "/assets/myimages/myimage.png";

Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(Doc);
PdfWriter pdfwriter= PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);

Doc.Open();
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath);
image.ScalePercent(106f,90f);
Doc.Add(image);
//adding elements using itextshart pdf
AddPDf(pdfwriter,Doc);

//to add html in pdf
//  htmlparser.Parse(stringReader);


OnEndPage(pdfwriter, Doc);
Doc.Close();
email_send(Doc.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();


public void email_send( string filename)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("reciever@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
        mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment((Server.MapPath(filename.ToString())));
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypass");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);

    }
```

The error i get is :

```
Could not find file         

  {"Could not find file 'C:\\Admin\\iTextSharp.text.Document'.":"C:   \\Admin\\iTextSharp.text.Document"}
```

Comment: _"but with no any success"_ - please read [ask] and explain what _does_ happen. Why do you call `Response.End()`, did you try reading the documentation for that method?

Comment: I have edit my code. Please check

Comment: Now you should change the title as you are not sending email after Response.End anymore. But what is the matter? Email is not sent? Document is not attached?

Comment: You are not writing the pdf to the filesystem, so how would you load it from disk with that attachment constructor? oO

Create a memory stream to store your pdf and pass the content bytes to the response and the stream to your mail attachment!?

Comment: COeDev can you post your memory stream suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you're passing the `Doc` object reference to your `email_send` method, instead of the file path.
I made a somewhat similar emailing solution by reading the document to a `MemoryStream` and passing that as the attachment.

```
public void email_send(Document d)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("reciever@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
    mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(d, ms);
    System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
    Attachment attach = new Attachment(ms, ct);

    mail.Attachments.Add(attach);

    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypass");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);

    writer.Flush();
    writer.Dispose();
    ms.Dispose();

}
```

Call it `email_send(Doc)`.

Comment: Hello now the email send but it is attached an noname file without any pdf extention. The file is 0kb

Comment: Did you use this latest version, I edited a hew typos about 10min ago.

Comment: Yes and i am geting a noname file 0kb as attachment.